# what is the fastest way to restore MySQL database without using dump files

Tags: mysql, backup

what is the best procedure to quickly restore the MySQL database without using dump files. can any body help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is possible if you have physical files. whice storage engine of MySQL you are using? Please refer below link for more options :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files

Comment: I am using InnoDB storage engine. I have set innodb_file_per_table = ON while creating tables. So, I have physical files  mytable.frm and mytable.ibd and ibdata1. Can I restore MySQL data using these 3 files or is there any dependent files. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse a physical files restore will be quicker than loading a dump. So, if you have full physical backup / snapshot of mysql data-directory - you can go fast!

(Below answer assumes that you have physical backup available.)

**Tables are MyISAM:**

> Stop mysql
>
> Copy database folder to mysql datadir
>
> Correct permissions
>
> Start mysql

**Tables are InnoDB:**

If we have InnoDB tables in the picture then things are not as simple. Considering you have Xtrabackup.

You will have  to import tables one after another.

Refer [Importing-Exporting-Tables-using-Xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/importing_exporting_tables_ibk.html.) OR [how-to-recover-a-single-innodb-table-from-a-full-backup](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/01/25/how-to-recover-a-single-innodb-table-from-a-full-backup/)
(For this to work you should have used xtrabackup as backup option.)

**Splitting mysqldump**

If you want to extract only one database from full mysqldump then you might want to [extract single database from mysqldump](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/how-to-recipes-for-mysqldumpsplitter) and load it (saves you from loading full dump).